# Navbar becomes translucent and inactive when scrolling over background images

Tags: html, css

When scrolling over sections only containing background images the navigation bar becomes translucent and inactive.

I would like the navigation bar to remain active while keeping it's styles throughout the whole website.

I am only using HTML and CSS here. StackOverflow wouldn't let me post if I included the css because it said it was too much code.

Can someone please help me figure out what to write for the CSS to fix this?

I included only the related code in the fiddle.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/makemommaproud/7q8pxg76/

```
 <header>
   <div class="container">
     <div id="branding">
       <h1>Name</h1>
     </div>
     <nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: No, we would need to see the css. Post it on an external site and reference it here. (Pastebin maybe?)

Comment: Save your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ and update your answer.

Comment: @Cagy79 I edited it into the original post. This is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow. If there's anything else I should include please let me know.

Comment: @JSideris I edited it into the original post. This is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow. If there's anything else I should include please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the opacity in the showcase to 1:

```
#showcase{
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top:;
    background:url("http://travel.home.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/travel/fullset/2015/08/03/top-florida-beaches/key-west-beach-florida.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.966.725.suffix/1491580836931.jpeg") no-repeat 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

another option is to add a z index to the header:

```
header{
    background: white;
    color: #282e34;
    padding-top: 0px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: black px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px #666;
    position: fixed; /* Added for fixed navbar */
    width: 100%; /* Added for fixed navbar */
    z-index: 100;
}
```